# Issues with date_diff php, comparing nowtime/nowdate, to SQL saved datetime

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // get date SQL format
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($today)); // get date SQL format¨

    $today = new DateTime($today);
    $compare = new DateTime($row['date']);

    $interval = date_diff($today, $compare);

    echo $interval->format("%H") .'<br>';
    echo $interval->format("%i") .'<br>';
    echo $interval->format("%s") .'<br>';
    die();
```

Something is very wrong, i want the time difference between a post in my SQL database and NowTime

```
 $row['date']
```

is 2013-03-25 14:22:53 inserted as datetime in my table, for some reason i get a odd downcounting output?

Comment: you can use `time()` for the current timestamp, `$today = new DateTime(time());`

Comment: thanks, does it return datetime?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the database query to do it.

`SELECT DATEDIFF(date,NOW()) as DateDifference FROM table`

Unsure why people keep insiting on doing db date comparisons in php rather than the DB. Its considerably quicker and less resource and tidier code to do it on query then just compare the result as it spits out the day differential of the dates. (date may be a protected column name so you may need to enclose it in ` or change it to a different column name.